# Data viewer in SSIS not showing all records

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I am using SSIS in visual studio for a data analysis task where I am comparing two databases
and trying to identify records that appear in one set and not the other. I have enabled dataviewer to see the details of the records however not all the records appear. For example in the attached image there is a difference of 20 records however only 18 appear. I have pressed the green play button but no more appear. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you've already clicked the Play symbol and the first 2 rows were displayed although I'm not 100% sold on this explanation as I would expect it to display 18 rows then 2.

Quick attempt at a repro. This should page 4 times

```
SELECT TOP 25 row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
,replicate('x', 4000) AS c2
FROM sys.all_columns
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

We can observe that total rows are cumulative so the next probable explanation would be an error was generated such that the 2 other rows weren't able to be sent to the Data Viewer.

Without seeing your package, it'll be difficult to reproduce this. Were it me, I'd
Add a Multicast operation before the data viewer. This allows the package to run "normal."  Then add a second output to the multicast and route it to a new flat file destination. Run package, get the 20 rows, 18 displayed situation and compare that to the flat file output.